# Moving the on-click directive in to a custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive and a template:

*sortable_column_header.js.coffee:*

```
sortableColumnHeader = ->
  return {
    restrict: 'A'
    replace: true
    scope:
      sortReverse: '=sortreverse'
      tfield: '@'

    templateUrl: 'angular/templates/sortable_column_header.html'
  }

angular
  .module 'dashboard'
  .directive 'sortableColumnHeader', [
    sortableColumnHeader
  ]
```

*templates/sortable_column_header.html.haml*

```
%th.order-column
  {{tfield}}
  %span.order-arrow
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-up{ng: {show: '{{sortReverse}}'}}
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-down{ng: {show: '{{!sortReverse}}'}}
```

stripped down controller:

```
DashboardController = () ->
  vm = @
  vm.sortType = 'name'
  vm.sortReverse = false
  return

angular
  .module 'dashboard'
  .controller 'DashboardController', [
    DashboardController
  ]
```

I am attaching ng-click directive to this custom directive. At the moment I am doing it like this:

```
%th{sortable_column_header: true, ng: {click: 'vm.sortType = "name"; vm.sortReverse = !vm.sortReverse'}, tfield: 'Campaign Name', sortReverse: 'vm.sortReverse'}
```

It is a *veeeerrrryyyyyy* long line of code and it can definitely be refactored to be a part of the directive. How can I move:

```
ng: {click: 'vm.sortType = "name"; vm.sortReverse = !vm.sortReverse'}
```

inside of the directive? So I can for example bind just a sortType from outside scope as this is the only thing that changes? It must have something to do with a **link** method but I couldn't figure out how to do it and there is the end of the day for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is something like this:

```
sortableColumnHeader = ->
  return {
    restrict: 'A'
    replace: true
    scope:
      sortReverse: '=sortreverse'
      tfield: '@'
    link: (scope, element, attrs)->
      element.bind 'click', -> 
      // Your code here

    templateUrl: 'angular/templates/sortable_column_header.html'
  }

angular
  .module 'dashboard'
  .directive 'sortableColumnHeader', [
    sortableColumnHeader
  ]
```

Comment: do I need to .find(th)? element is th, when it gets replaced all the attibutes should be moved over? or not...

Comment: No, you actually don't need that now that I'm looking closer. I didn't realize you had set replace to true.

Comment: replace is set to true because there is a problem with tr if it is not. it gets rendered outside of the table! same if I change restricted to 'E' for some strange reason it gets rendered outside of the table

Comment: another one - you probably don't need $(element)- element should be enough JQlite already did the magic. I was over complicating my link method didn't realize it is that easy...

Comment: You're correct on all of these counts. I didn't really test before posting haha. Also, sorry the coffee script was all jacked up. I never use it.

Comment: np cool I thank you! coffee just looks better in my opinion:)

Comment: I actually agree, but none of the projects I work on professionally use it, so unless I force myself to use it on the side, it doesn't happen :/

Answer (score 0):

create a directive and in it, in the link method

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("click", function (event) {
// Write your code here
}
```